# While-loop syntax explanation

Tags: c#, while-loop, xsd

Was reading through [this](https://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/08/18/unit-testing-xsd-schemas/) while researching XSD Validation. Came across this piece of code.

```
private static IEnumerable<ValidationEventArgs> RunValidation(string inputXml, bool includeHelperSchema)
{
    var schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
    schemaSet.Add(schemaUnderTest);

    if (includeHelperSchema)
    {
        schemaSet.Add(helperSchema);
    }

    var readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings()
    {
        Schemas = schemaSet,
        ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema,
        ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings,
    };

    var events = new List<ValidationEventArgs>();
    readerSettings.ValidationEventHandler += (s, e) => { events.Add(e); };

    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(inputXml), readerSettings))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
            ;
    }

    return events;
}
```

Could someone please explain to me what is the purpose of the semicolon being placed here?

```
while (reader.Read())
        ;
```

Removing gives an error "`Invalid expression term '}' ; expected`".

Comment: Please point out line.

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements), where `while` keyword defined:

```
while_statement
    : 'while' '(' boolean_expression ')' embedded_statement
    ;
```

As you see, `while` statement must end with `;`. So, if `embedded_statement` is empty, you'll get:

```
while (boolean_expression)
    ;
```

instead of:

```
while (boolean_expression)
    embedded_statement
    ;
```

`embedded_statement` can be one line expression like `Console.WriteLine()` or a block of code in `{ }` braces:

```
while (boolean_expression)
{
    embedded_statement
}
;
```

Here, `;` is not necessary, you can write simple:

```
while (boolean_expression)
{
    embedded_statement
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know that it was required to end it that way since I've always been accustomed to use `while (boolean_expression)
{
    embedded_statement
}`. +1 for the link provided.

Answer (score 0):

Put the body for while loop

```
    while(reader.Read()){ 
    // your code there
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (reader.Read());
```

The semicolon is just causing the while loop to continually evaluate `reader.Read()` until it returns `false`

Another way to write this could be

```
var result = reader.Read()
while (result)
{
   result = reader.Read();
}
```